# Java | Хранение экземпляра класса

Tags: java, telegram-bot

Делаю бота для Telegram на Java. При разработке столкнулся с тем, что система хранит где-то объект и отправляет его параметры несмотря на то, что объект пересоздан.

**Как это должно работать**

1. Пользователь что-то пишет боту 
2. Бот получает из класса Main - HashMap с объектами User, где ключ - уникальный идентификатор пользователя внутри Telegram. 
3. Если данных в HashMap по пользователю нет - бот создаёт экземпляр класса User() 
 3.1 Конструктор в User делает запрос к базе данных и сохраняет в переменных все значения (nickname, id, TelegramID и так далее). 
4. Вызывается метод isRegister() класса User, который проверяет заполнился ли объект конструктором и если нет, то пользователь не зарегистрирован. Если да - сохраняет экземпляр класса в HashMap 
5. Отправляется в ответ сообщение о том что пользователь: зарегистрирован / не зарегистрирован 
 
**Как это работает сейчас**

1. Пользователь что-то пишет боту 
2. Бот проверяет есть ли данные в HashMap (их нет, потому что программа пока не сохраняет их там) 
3. Бот создаёт экземпляр класса User и заполняет его данными из базы конструктором 
4. Если экземпляр пуст, то пишет что пользователь не зарегистрирован. Если заполнен - пишет что зарегистрирован 
5. Если пользователь не зарегистрирован, при попытке что-то написать, каждый раз выводится сообщение что юзер не зарегистрирован. 
6. Создаём в базе данных запись с данными пользователя 
7. Пишем боту и он отвечает что пользователь зарегистрирован 
8. Меняем идентификатор пользователя в базе на любой другой 
9. Бот до сих пор пишет что пользователь зарегистрирован и выводит данные ранее заполненного объекта User. Даже если боту написать с другого аккаунта - всё равно выводит данные первого аккаунта

Не совсем понятно где сохраняется объект User и почему сохраняется, когда каждый раз должен создаваться заново и заново наполняться или быть пустым (если данных нет).

---

**Код** 
*Core*

```
package org.teateam.Chat;

import org.teateam.Main;
import org.teateam.TelegramApi;
import org.teateam.User;
import org.telegram.telegrambots.meta.TelegramBotsApi;
import org.telegram.telegrambots.meta.exceptions.TelegramApiException;

public class Core extends Thread{

    @Override
    public void run(){
        System.out.println("Chat flow started");

        // Telegram startup section
        Main.telegramApi = new TelegramApi();

        TelegramBotsApi botsApi = new TelegramBotsApi();

        try {
            botsApi.registerBot(Main.telegramApi);
        }
        catch (TelegramApiException ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        // End section
    }

    public static void validateText(String text, long from_id) {
        User user = Main.users.get(from_id);
        if(user == null){
            // If not online
            user = new User(from_id);
            if(user.isRegister()) {
                Main.telegramApi.sendTextMessage(from_id, "Вы зарегистрированы. Nickname: " + user.nickname + ". Tid: " + user.tid);
            }
            else{
                Main.telegramApi.sendTextMessage(from_id, "Вы не зарегистрированы");
            }
        }
        else{
            Main.telegramApi.sendTextMessage(from_id, "Your nick is " + user.nickname);
        }
    }
}
```

Обрабатывает новые события в методе validateText(), пришедшие от метода onUpdateReceived() в классе TelegramApi 
*TelegramApi*

```
package org.teateam;

import org.teateam.Chat.Core;
import org.telegram.telegrambots.bots.TelegramLongPollingBot;
import org.telegram.telegrambots.meta.api.methods.send.SendMessage;
import org.telegram.telegrambots.meta.api.objects.Update;
import org.telegram.telegrambots.meta.exceptions.TelegramApiException;

public class TelegramApi extends TelegramLongPollingBot {
    private SendMessage message = new SendMessage();

    public TelegramApi(){
        System.out.println("Bot has been started success");
    }

    public void sendTextMessage(long peer_id, String text){
        this.message.setChatId(peer_id).setText(text);
        try {
            execute(this.message);
        }
        catch (TelegramApiException tEx){
            System.out.println("Exception in org.teateam.TelegramApi: " + tEx);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpdateReceived(Update update) {
        if(update.hasMessage() && update.getMessage().hasText()){
            // If text
            Core.validateText(update.getMessage().getText(), update.getMessage().getChatId());
            System.out.println(" ");
            System.out.println("New message: " + update.getMessage().getText());
            System.out.println("From ID: " + update.getMessage().getChatId());
            System.gc();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String getBotUsername() {
        return Main.getBotUsername();
    }

    @Override
    public String getBotToken() {
        return Main.getAccess_token();
    }

}
```

validateText() проверяет есть ли объект User в HashMap (его всегда нет в данной реализации) и создаёт объект класса User. 
 
*User*

```
package org.teateam;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class User {
    public long tid;
    public String nickname;
    public int accessLevel;
    public int id;
    public boolean online;
    public int room;

    public User(long tid){
        // Add data from database
        String query = "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `tid` = '" + tid + "' LIMIT 1;";
        ArrayList<String> result = MySQL.select(query);
        if(!result.isEmpty()) {
            this.tid = Long.parseLong(result.get(0));
            this.nickname = result.get(1);
            this.accessLevel = Integer.parseInt(result.get(2));
            this.id = Integer.parseInt(result.get(3));
            this.online = false;
            this.room = 0;
        }
    }

    public boolean isRegister(){
        return this.nickname != null;
    }
}
```

User, при создании, делает запрос к базе через метод select() класса MySQL и получает от него ArrayList, которым заполняет самого себя. Если MySQL возвращает пустой ArrayList, то экземпляр класса не заполняется.
*MySQL*

```
package org.teateam;

import java.sql.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MySQL {
    private static final String host = "";
    private static final int port = 3306;
    private static final String user = "";
    private static final String password = "";
    private static final String database = "";
    private static final String url = "jdbc:mysql://" + host + ":" + port + "/" + database + "?useUnicode=true&useJDBCCompliantTimezoneShift=true&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=UTC";

    private static Connection connection;
    private static Statement statement;
    private static ResultSet resultSet;
    private static ResultSetMetaData resultSetMetaData;

    private static ArrayList<String> result = new ArrayList<>();

    /**
     *
     * @param query For example: SELECT `login` FROM `users` WHERE `id` = 1 LIMIT 1;
     * @return ArrayList<String>
     */
    public static ArrayList<String> select(String query){
        try{
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);
            statement = connection.createStatement();
            resultSet = statement.executeQuery(query);
            resultSetMetaData = resultSet.getMetaData();

            try {
                while (resultSet.next()) {
                    for(int i = 0; i < resultSetMetaData.getColumnCount(); i++){
                        result.add(resultSet.getString(i + 1 ));
                        System.out.println(resultSet.getString(i + 1));
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (SQLException sqlEx){
                sqlEx.printStackTrace();
                return result;
            }
        }
        catch (SQLException sqlEx){
            sqlEx.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally {
            try{ connection.close(); } catch (SQLException se) { /* TODO anything */ se.printStackTrace();}
            try{ statement.close(); } catch (SQLException se) { /* TODO anything */ se.printStackTrace();}
            try{ resultSet.close(); } catch (SQLException se) { /*  TODO anything */ se.printStackTrace();}
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В классе MySQL есть private static ArrayList result, который хранит значения. В случае, если данные есть в базе - он наполняется и потом возвращается в User. В случае, если данных нет в базе, но до этого этот объект User уже вызывался- с result ничего не происходит и он возвращается с последним значением. Собственно, result и хранил в себе все данные, по которым заполнялся User и не переопределялся в конце.

Решено добавлением следующей строки в начале метода select() класса MySQL:

```
result.clear();
```

Что позволяет каждый раз очищать ArrayList от последнего запроса.